# Protocol for Real Time Streaming from Android Device to Wowza Server?

Tags: android, video-streaming, rtmp, http-live-streaming, wowza

My goal is to stream the audio/video content in real time from Android mobile to Wowza Server. 
1- As I understand, the protocol for the Wowza's incoming and outgoing(broadcasted) streams can be different. True?
2- If that is so, then I can either upload my video data through HLS protocol or RTMP protocol. 
3- I'm little bit familiar with these protocols after searching here and there, but I don't have enough knowledge to make a decision which protocol will be best to stream recorded audio and video data to Wowza server in real time, so that it can be broadcasted and seen through HLS protocol. So help in selecting the best protocol will be appreciated.

It should be noted that the video will be recorded and streamed in real time, that means I will have to get the encoded buffer from MediaCodec and send it to the Wowza Server.

Again, if the point 1 above is true then it means my only concern should be to choose the best protocol for the Wowza's inbound stream.

Any advice regarding Android OS versions, SDK vs. NDK etc. will be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: To the troll who gave me -1 
Mind explaining what was so annoying to you?

Answer (score 0):

1 - True.
2 - RTMP. HLS is a pull base protocol over HTTP. fine for server to client, but not great for client to server. 
3 - This is not a question.

Protocol it completely independent of OS choice.

Comment: Thanks. Some protocols' implementation is available in the form of source code at git etc. Some can be used at NDK, that means if I make use of those sources then there could be some issues if we have our content being produced at the java side . That's where the OS version comes in. If you are familiar with Android then you would know that video capture techniques at Android Lollipop are different than its predecessors.